# PHP ternary operator returning different value just because of newlines

Tags: php, formatting, ternary-operator

Can someone enlighten me what might be wrong in the following code?

```
$wOwner = ($owner instanceof IIdentity ? $owner->getName() : $owner);
var_dump($wOwner);
$wOwner = ($owner instanceof IIdenity
        ? $owner->getName()
        : $owner);
var_dump($wOwner);
```

I get following output

```
string '1555' (length=4)
object(Member)[2] //snipping out the object properties
```

I am interested in extending such type of expression in string concatenating e.g.

```
$msg = 'Answer is' . ( $expr ? 'yes' : 'no' );
```

Comment: Why don't you use simple if - else statement?

Comment: I *am* using it, but I am just wondering why the two result in different output when the only difference is a newline character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing related with new line, just because `IIdentity` is **different** from `IIdenity`!